# How can I make jQuery execute only after button click and not on page load

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I tryed mostly all suggestions about this manner, but I couldn't figure out how to execute javascript effect on button id="submit" click, and not on page load.
By the way this is not my code, the code is taken from http://visualidiot.com/articles/doge

This is the Html

```
<body class="such shibe">
    <img src="images/googletr.png">
    <div class="searchContainer">
        <form>
            <input id="field" name="field" type="text" />
            <button id="submit" href="arama.html" />
        </form>
    </div>


    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
    <script src="jquery.doge.js"></script>
    <script>
        $($.doge);
    </script>
</body>
```

and js file jquery.doge.js

```
    (function () {
//  such plugin
$.doge = function(tings) {
    //  very jquery
    var doge = $('body').css('font-family', 'Russo One, sans-serif');

    var r = function(arr) {
        if(!arr) arr = tings; return arr[Math.floor(Math.random() * arr.length)];
    };

    var dogefix = [
        '<img style="height:100px" src="images/img.png">', '<img style="height:150px" src="images/img.png">', '<img style="height:50px" src="images/img.png">',
        '<img style="height:200px" src="images/img.png">', '<img style="height:250px" src="images/img.png">',
        '<img style="height:300px" src="images/img.png">','<img style="height:350px" src="images/img.png">',
    ];

    var very = doge.append('<div class="such overlay" />').children('.such.overlay').css({
        position: 'fixed',
        left: 0,
        right: 0,
        top: 0,
        bottom: 0,
        pointerEvents: 'none'
    });

    setInterval(function() {

        $('.such.overlay').append(
            '<span style="position: absolute; left: ' + Math.random()  *100 + '%;top: ' + Math.random()  *100 + '%;font-size: ' + Math.max(24, (Math.random() * 50 + 100)) + 'px; color: rgb(' + Math.round(Math.random() * 0) + ', ' + Math.round(Math.random() * 0) + ', ' + Math.round(Math.random() * 0) + ');">'
                + r(dogefix) +
            '</span>');        
    }, 50);
};
})(jQuery);;
```

Comment: For this you have to attach handler on `onclick` event.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should try this:

```
$('#submit').on('click', function(e){
    // Cancel the default event
    e.preventDefault();
    $($.doge);
});
```

Comment: Don't forget to set it as approved answer so users can know the issue is solved ;)

Answer (score 0):

Try something like:

```
$('#submit').on('click', function () {
  // your existing code
});
```